# Saving Kik conversations using VirtualBox Android device

Tags: android, virtual-machines

I'm using a virtual Android device on VirtualBox to chat using 
Kik. Kik doesn't officially support saving conversations, but can I do 
it using my setup?

My thoughts: when I take a snapshot of Andy (my VirtualBox Android 
device), that snapshot should contain my last n Kik conversations in 
some form. Kik doesn't store conversations permanently, but does let 
you scroll back through some number of them (the storage is local on 
your device, not remote on their servers).

I tried "shared folders", but I couldn't get this to work, even after 
trying to install "guest additions" (which didn't appear to work 
either: I'm guessing they're only supported on certain platforms).

Has anyone looked into doing something like this? Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like what you're doing (saving snapshots and scrolling through the message history) is already working as a solution for you. What's your question?

Comment: Actually, that's my backup plan. I'm assuming that the kik messages are somewhere in the .sav or .vdi file and can be extracted programatically. I 'grep'ed and found nothing, but, of course, there's no guarantee that the messages are stored in plain text-- they could be compressed or even images or something.

Comment: Setup a port forward and connect to the Android device using ADB. From there you should be able to access what you (e.g. if it is written to a file you can read it). If you can't, get root on the vm.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to [mount the VM's VDI HD image](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#VDI) and then look through the file system for the conversation logs. If you can't easily find the logs in the file system, you'll need to reverse engineer the Kik application to determine where it's storing the conversation logs.